# phusion passenger application is supposed to run on Plesk and throws an error

Tags: passenger, plesk, openhab

I am trying to run an instance of openhab Cloud on my server which is administered with Plesk.
It wasn’t working yet, but I already had the site up and running. Since there was an error, I wanted to set up the page again and since then I always get the following error:
[ D 2023-06-06 18:20:59.8321 4155856/T1 age/Spa/SpawnEnvSetupperMain.cpp:747 ]: shellName = 'zsh' detected as supporting '-l': true
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4hvo.png)

Detailed diagnostics shows this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0SEz.png)

I was looking for the error message but it doesn't seem to be a very common error. Checked every link without any progress.

Added

```
    "spawnEnv": {
        "shell": "/bin/bash"
    },
```

to config.json (was a suggestion of ChatGPT)

Tried out nodejs 14 and 16.
Changed nginx settings, but without results.
Several re installations and so on.
I've tried to make it work for a few month now.

I think it's a problem with Passenger but I'm not sure. It would be a great help if somebody could confirm that this is a Passenger problem.

Thanks in advance!
Best regards